# Including top links(login/logout sign up under Account as dropdown select values)

Tags: login, wishlist, toplinks, logout

subject :—- Including top links(login/logout sign up under Account as dropdown select values)

I want to add login signup and login/out options inside account i.e account as dropdown menu where login , sign up and login/logout should be inside Account dropdown. Can please somebody guide me how to do this.. I tried but is default . .. Please help.. such that it should not effect the functionality . . . ..

regards